# Populate Attribute and values to all parent nodes of the XML file from 4th parent node

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, nodes

I am new to XSLT and would like to add Attribute and Value of the same to all parent nodes starting from 2nd parent node. here the logic should be the if there is Main node, the attribute(Mainattribute) should be one time and for rest of all parent nodes under the Main node should have different attribute(childattribute) which should be same across all other than Main node.

we have a input xml like below : It is just have some fields only, ideally there will be more tags and may differ.

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <Header>
                <Main>
                    <Parent2>
                        <status>12</status>
                        <statusmsg>Helo</status_text>
                    </Parent2>
                    <Parent3>
                        <Child1>112</Child1>
                        <Child2>Hai</Child2>
                    </Parent3>
                    <Parent4>
                        <Child3>Valley</Child3>
                        <Parent5>
                            <Child7>Kind</Child1>
                            <Child8>Pls</Child2>
                        </Parent5>
                    </Parent4>
                </Main>
            </Header>
```

The output should be like below:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <Header>
            <Main Mainattribute="1">
                <Parent2 childattribute="1">
                    <status>12</status>
                    <statusmsg>Helo</status_text>
                </Parent2>
                <Parent3 childattribute="1">
                    <Child1>112</Child1>
                    <Child2>Hai</Child2>
                </Parent3>
                <Parent4 childattribute="1">
                    <Child3>Valley</Child3>
                    <Parent5 childattribute="1">
                        <Child7>Kind</Child1>
                        <Child8>Pls</Child2>
                    </Parent5>
                </Parent4>
            </Main>
        </Header>
```

Can some one please share XSLT for the same. i have tried so many cases but not able to achieve it. thank you

Below is the XSLT tried for first Main node, but somehow getting error and couldnt proceed further.

```
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
            <!-- Template to copy all the elements -->
            <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template match="Main">
                <Main>
                    <xsl:attribute name="Mainattribute">
                        <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>
                </Main>
            </xsl:template>



        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and share the XSLT that you have tried? It may need some tweaking to achieve the result. Also, the input XML shared has incorrect closing tags. Please correct them too so as to get a well-formed XML.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply, have shared the XSL tried but no luck.

Comment: `<statusmsg>Helo</status_text>` is not valid XML. Neither is `<Child7>Kind</Child1>` and `<Child8>Pls</Child2>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enhancing @Aniket V's answer, you can resort to modes instead of depending on the name of the tag:

```xslt
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Main">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="Mainattribute"><xsl:value-of select="1"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="parent_mode"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="parent_mode">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="childattribute"><xsl:value-of select="1"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Update**

If you waht to update all XML elements which have children (but not the top level element), then this transformation is yours:

```xslt
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Main" priority="1">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="Mainattribute"><xsl:value-of select="1"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[child::* and ancestor::*]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="childattribute"><xsl:value-of select="1"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the code only works for top two parent nodes, not for all parent nodes. we dont Need of having for Loop to check the parent nodes?

Comment: @Ven I updated my answer to process all elements which have children (but not the top level element). Hope that this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much Adrian. It works very well.Kudos to you.

Comment: hello, I know i came back with the existing XSLT but, i have got some issue that in my source file, we are getting root node as :  <Header xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">. i.e. appended with namespace. Which has to be removed, but while i tried with mode = "remove-namespace" and omit namesapce etc, but couldnt get succeeded. Can you please let me know where to add this in the above working code. I am bit confused of where to add the code to remove namespace. Thank you

Comment: The problem is that `<xsl:copy/>` copies the element including the namespace declarations. You can avoid this by inserting an element with the same (local) name instead of copying. For that, replace all three occurrences of `<xsl:copy/>` with `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">`. Btw. the XSLT after the "Update" above needs some `priority=...` attributes to properly prefer the `match="Main"` over `match="*"` template. I add this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are quite close with the XSLT changes. Please modify the templates as below.

Template for `<Main>`

```
<xsl:template match="Main">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="Mainattribute">
            <xsl:value-of select="1" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Template for nodes having name `Parent`.

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(name(), 'Parent')]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="childattribute">
            <xsl:value-of select="1" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thank you, but the problem is i cannot go with the "Parent" matching as the node name may change. Because we are going to get some files with different names of XML tags. But we should insert the childattribute according to all the nodes.